# When doing require for npm package, what is meaning of slash in package name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

While "requiring" non-local NodeJS modules, what is the meaning of slash in module name?

Example:
from ShellJS npm module's github page (link: https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#javascript)

`require('shelljs/global');`
`require('shelljs/make');`

Upon looking at the directory structure of ShellJS github project, I notice that both **global.js** and **make.js** are both at same level as **shell.js** which is the main entry point of the module as per its package.json. So what does the slash mean in the package name and how, in above example, is the path to "global" and "make" resolved?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Slash (as it primary use), is just simply used for file paths.

`require('shelljs/global')` will load script of `global.js` file.

`require('shelljs/make')` will load script of `make.js` file.

However, `require('shelljs')` will load script of `shell.js`. 
Why? Let's look at the content of `package.json`: It's `"main": "./shell.js"` that makes the magic.

Comment: Pretty interesting!! Does that mean that we can also do something like `require('shelljs/scripts/run-tests.js')`? And can accessing scripts like this  be blocked for your personal repos?

Comment: We cannot do that since `run-tests.js` is not a `CommonJs` module (no `module.exports = ...`, so that we cannot require it). But we still be able to access other files, e.g: `require('shelljs/src/chmod')`. I'm not sure if there are any ways to limit the accessing from outside of package.