# How can npm install inside a sub module? mssql not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, node.js, npm

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621978/when-doing-require-for-npm-package-what-is-meaning-of-slash-in-package-name) question, they say that `require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')` should find `msnodesqlv8.js` file in the `mssql` folder. Fair enough.

But how can I install it?

On the [github page](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#microsoft--contributors-node-v8-driver-for-nodejs-for-sql-server) for `mssql` (as adviced in [this github issue](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/338)) they say that to install `msnodesqlv8` I should do a simple `npm install msnodesqlv8`, but how would that work? It just added a `msnodesqlv8` folder **next to** the existing `mssql` folder, and added nothing inside.

Because then, `const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')` fails (`cannot find module 'mssql/msnodesqlv8'`);

`const sql = require('msnodesqlv8')` fails too, because when I call a function I get `... is not a function` because the `sql` variable doesn't have everything from `mssql`.

What did I do wrong?

Shouldn't there be an option with the `npm install` in order for the driver module to be installed **in** the first one?

Something wrong with my `package.json` maybe? (Should I have changed it after installing `msnodesqlv8`?)

Comment: Those are *not* the docs or repos for [msnodesqlv8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesqlv8). Check the package page. Did you try `npm install msnodesqlv8 --save` ?

Comment: I hadn't used `--save`, I did it now, what is it supposed to change? (I still get the same errors). `msnodesqlv8` should be able to be used as just the driver for `mssql`, the package page does the connection very differently,  I tried but I don't see where I'm supposed to put my login and password, even in their sample. Why does the connection string only mention the server, database and driver?

Comment: If you read the *wrong* docs, you aren't going to fix anything. The example **does** show how to authenticate. The correct way, without username/password. SQL Server connection strings are *very* well documented anyway, you can just google for `sql server connection string`. All of this you can find with minimal effort, which makes this question ... not quite suited to SO

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you mind writing an answer so I can accept it?